# Can multiple lists in SharePoint 2013 share same workflow designed in Nintex 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

Requirement: 68 words forms being migrated to SharePoint 2013.
Nintex Version: 2013
Case: Each workflow is same.
Issue: Each workflow have emails which needs to send links of current list's display form, edit form or assign flexi tasks notifications. So, can we have one copy of workflow which dynamically sends URLs across lists?
Exploration: Tried re-usable workflow with send and get data. This didn't work as each instance of re-usable workflow have unique GUID. Am I missing anything?

Comment: - Are all lists within the same Site? 
- Do the Documents share the same Content Type? 
- What is the starting event of those Workflow?

Comment: Yes, all are within same site. There is no content type but would it had helped? Start condition->new/always, modify->column value change to specific value